# Validate client certificate without server key nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a client certificate and the associated private key. I am setting up a (proxy) server that should validate the client certificate. Is there a way using nodejs to validate the client certificate, without having the server key?

Comment: The only thing you need to validate a certificate (client or server) is the certificate of the CA that signed it.

Comment: @Marc I can get the certificate chain from the server where the client should connect to. Once I get this certificate chain, any idea how to validate the client certificate in nodejs?

Comment: As @Marc noted, the server certificate chain is not relevant to validating the client the certificate.